# How many people fully understand the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, soft-question

What is a rough order of magnitude estimate? $$ $$ There is a thread on Meta about this question, http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/567/rapid-closing-of-questions/#Item_0

Comment: I imagine this will be closed soon.  Please read the FAQ. 

Comment: Isn't this appropriate for meta?

Comment: I have no idea why they closed this fascinating question,Micheal.None whatsoever.

Comment: This question doesn't have much to do with math or math education and is therefore not appropriate for MO, which has a very specific purpose and is not a chat room. As for the meta tag, well most questions tagged with it are closed so I don't know what purpose it's serving exactly...

Comment: "The site works best for well-defined questions: math questions that actually have a specific answer. You'll notice that there is the occasional question making a list of something, asking about the workings of the mathematical community, or something else which isn't really a math question. Such questions can be helpful to the community, but it is extremely tricky to ask them in a way that produces a useful response. So if you're new to the site, we suggest you stick to asking precise math questions until you learn about the quirks of the community and the strengths of the medium."

Comment: Also from the FAQ:  "There's a place for discussion about mathematics, but it isn't MathOverflow. Blogs and threaded discussion forums are a more appropriate place for discussions."

Comment: Also, "meta" means tea.mathoverflow.net which is for discussions about MathOverflow.  The [meta] tag appears to be an independent misunderstanding of this by several different users.

Comment: @Andrew: if you think this question should be reopened, you should start a thread about it on meta.

Comment: Dear Michael,

The methods introduced by Wiles, and by Taylor and Wiles, in the two papers that proved FLT, as well as the methods introduced by Ribet in his earlier paper reducing FLT to Shimura--Taniyama, are at the heart of much modern work in algebraic number theory and automorphic forms,
so, such as the proofs of Serre's conj. and the Sato--Tate conj.

Conferences/workshops in these fields typically attract on the order of magnitude of 100 or so particants, which gives you some sense of the number of students/researchers thinking about these questions: its in the tens or hundreds, but ...

Comment: probably not in the thousands.  Of course, not all these people know all the details, but the people at the top of the field surely do.  (Of course, there is a question of what "understand" means exactly.  I don't know how many people have carefully studied *all* the details of the trace formula that underly Jacquet--Langlands, Langlands--Tunnell, and base-change, and have *also* carefully studied the details of $p$-adic Hodge theory that is used in the arguments.  But certainly the top people do understand the significance of these techinques, and are fluent in their use and application, ...

Comment: and understand both the overall structure and strategy, as well the technical details, of the proof of FLT itself (and various more recent related results).

Comment: This question seems reasonably precise to me, and as Emerton explains it has a correct answer.

Comment: I agree with Noah that as Emerton's answer suggests there is a precise (OP only asks for order of magnitude) answer to this question.  It's borderline as to the mathematical relevance, but I would not mind seeing Emerton's answer as a real answer instead of as a comment.  It could be historically interesting to observe, years from now, the average number of participants in typical conferences in this area of research. I think the MO community would do well to take a long-term view of MO!

Comment: José, surely that is very frivolous interpretation of "questions that admit a precise answer" from the FAQ. There is a world of difference between a guesstimate of attendance at conferences and a serious analysis of a number of researchers working on a certain topic, let alone being capable of understanding a certain topic! The usefulness of an ad hoc answer for any future historians of science will be close to nil. And I think that gossip has no place at MO.

Comment: Dear Victor, I don't think that this is a question of gossip.  Especially from an amateur interested in FLT, but incapable of understanding the proof (I don't know whether or not the OP is such), 
or even from a grad student or mathematician in another field, it is a reasonable question.  Since accepting that FLT is proved in that case is a matter of deferring to authority, it is reasonable to ask how widely disseminated the understanding of the proof is.  

Comment: Dear Matt, I feel like deferring to your authority is the only viable option:) 

Comment: This question has a meta thread devoted to it: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/567/rapid-closing-of-questions/

Answer (score 53):

Dear Michael,

The methods introduced by Wiles, and by Taylor and Wiles, in the two papers that proved FLT, as well as the methods introduced by Ribet in his earlier paper reducing FLT to Shimura--Taniyama, are at the heart of much modern work in algebraic number theory and automorphic forms, such as (in addition to the proofs of Shimura--Taniyama and FLT) the proofs of Serre's conjectures and the Sato--Tate conjecture.

Conferences/workshops in these fields typically attract on the order of magnitude of 100 or so particants, which gives you some sense of the number of students/researchers thinking about these questions: its in the tens or hundreds, but probably not in the thousands. Of course, not all these people know all the details, but the people at the top of the field surely do. (Of course, there is a question of what "understand" means exactly. I don't know how many people have both carefully studied  all the details of the trace formula arguments that underly Jacquet--Langlands, Langlands--Tunnell, and base-change,  and also carefully studied the details of the p-adic Hodge theory and other arithmetic geometry that is used in the arguments. But certainly the top people do understand the significance of these techinques, and are fluent in their use and application, and understand both the overall structure and strategy, as well the technical details, of the proof of FLT itself (and of various more recent related results).

Finally, let me note that the best evidence for the final claim of the previous paragraph is that this is currently an extremely vibrant area of research, which has progressed at a rapid clip over the last ten years or so.  (The reason for this being that people have not only assimilated the arguments of Wiles/Taylor--Wiles but have improved upon them and pushed them further.)

Comment: Dear Matthew: I'm glad you took it upon yourself to answer this question. On first reading it, I was reminded of one of those popular misconceptions like 'only five people in the world understand general relativity.' It's certainly worthwhile to help interested amateurs gain a more sophisticated understanding of the scientific process. Your last paragraph makes the point most clearly.

Comment: re: p-adic Hodge theory, is it used in the published version of Wiles' proof?  The earlier version, with the gap that was later repaired, cited Faltings' paper on p-adic Hodge theory --- a work which was considered essentially correct but not completely clear in all of its arguments.  But I thought the Wiles and Taylor published work has no logical dependence on Faltings or on what one usually calls p-adic Hodge theory (e.g., comparison theorems using rings of p-adic periods).

Comment: (or are you referring to the proof of the full modularity conjecture which used heavier p-adic technology?)

Comment: Dear T.,  I think that you're certainly correct in one sense, but on the other hand, I think that the proof relies on Faltings's Theorem (Tate's conjecture), which uses p-adic Hodge theory (more precisely, Tate's p-divisible groups paper)(as well as many other things!), and the computation of the structure of the flat deformation ring uses some ideas that one could reasonably put (or at least, that I put) in the p-adic Hodge theory box.   So perhaps one shouldn't take my invocation of p-adic Hodge theory too seriously, but just take it as a metaphor for a certain flavour of technique.